# Running parameterized python script within bash script

Tags: python, bash

I have a python script that logs me in to a service. I do:

```
./login.py user@email.com 'pass'
```

in order to log in.

When I enter this command directly I successfully login. When I run the following script server returns 400.

```
PYAPIROOT="scriptpath/script"
PYLOGIN="./login.py"
LOGIN="user@email.com"
PASS="'pass'"

function login {
    echo -----------------------------
    echo
    cd $PYAPIROOT
    echo "Logging in "$LOGIN
    python "$PYLOGIN" "$LOGIN" "$PASS"
    echo $PYLOGIN $LOGIN $PASS
    echo -----------------------------
}

login
```

When I copy and run what is echo'ed I get 200. 
Why can't I log in using my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's the double-quoting:

```
PASS="'pass'"
```

Use this instead:

```
PASS="pass"
```

Comment: @Booyaches OK that's good then. How about upvoting and accepting the answer then?

Comment: Sure. I had to wait 15 mins from when the question was asked to accept any answer.